# HTML to PDF convertion and editing in iOS

Tags: html, ipad, pdf-generation, font-size

I am creating an iPad application for reading PDF, this PDF should be generated from a HTML file. I have seen some sample codes for converting HTML to PDF, and I think that part will be fine for me to implement.

I have seen some apps from from AppStore for reading PDF files, in that there is an option for increase the font size (not zooming), color style etc. When we increase the font size the text content automatically wrapping to next line. How can I implement this in my app? Any idea about how would they have done that?

I have seen in some posts that, it is not possible to edit a PDF file, so are they actually using PDF file or some other format?

Answer (score 1):

When rendering your PDF to show it to user, you can convert it in other formats like HTML and then allow user to change font-size, font-style. So your PDF remain unchanged. Also it is easy to manipulate HTML than binary formatted documents like PDF.

Comment: Actually what I need to do is, I have a PDF document at the server and user wants to download it and save locally in PDF format. So, what I am planning to do is, user can download the HTML format of PDF and converting it into PDF, so user can read as PDF. And I am thinking about how user can change the font size and all when reading. I thought it is possible with PDF, so should I keep the HTML content instead of converting to PDF? So user can change the font size as you said??